# validation for models in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I have a model:

```
class HelloRails < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :filename, :filevalidate
  include In4systemsModelCommon

  validates :filename, presence: true

  def update
      parameters = [self.filename, @current_user]
      parameters.map!{|p| ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote p}
      sql = "call stored_procedure(#{parameters.join(',')})"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

In the view I have a `text_field` called as `:filename`. When I click the submit button it calls this update method in model to call the stored proc to execute. Now validations are not working.

I dont want to accept `nil` for filename. How can I do this?

Comment: It doesn't validate because you are executing sql directly (`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`). Validations are only run when you use the *normal* ActiveRecord methods like `save` and `update_attributes`. What does your stored procedure look like? Is it really necessary? If not, try to use ActiveRecord like it was meant to be used.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. Is it possible to validate the field when its calling sql directly?

Comment: See my answer. Didn't try, but something like that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't validate because you are executing sql directly:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Validations are only run when you use the "normal" ActiveRecord methods like `save` and `update_attributes`. To run validations manually you can call `valid?` on your object.

Model:

```
def update
  return false unless self.valid? # validation failed: return false
  parameters = [self.filename, @current_user]
  parameters.map!{|p| ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote p}
  sql = "call stored_procedure(#{parameters.join(',')})"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  true
end
```

Then in your controller you have to check wether `@object.update` returns `true` or `false` and display errors in your view if necessary.

Controller:

```
# This is just an example. I don't know your code.
def update
  @object = HelloRails.find(params[:id])

  if @object.update
    redirect_to somewhere
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: yeah... bcz you gave me the idea to do that... and now i finished its working. The mistake is mine. Before i didnt have any update method in my controller. Thank you.